# How to solve my query with single for loop?

Tags: php, for-loop

How can I write the code for this in PHP language?

```
*
**
***
```

I want to print this stars shape in php, but the condition is by using single for loop. How is this possible?

My code is this where I am confused here:

```
<?php
$a="*";
for($b=1;$b<=3;$b++)
{
echo "*".$a."<br/>";
}
echo "<br/>";
?>
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?  What output do you get?  What is the difference between the two?

Comment: im confused, what shape are you trying to make?

Comment: I got this output mate,

**
**
**

But I want this output right away,

*
**
***

Comment: Sounds like homework to me

Comment: @KamalHasija What output are you expecting?

Comment: What do you expect? You are not even using `$b` in the loop...

Comment: @KamalHasija you need to update your post

Comment: Maybe you're looking for str_repeat? http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php

Comment: Check the post preview before posting. I'm guessing you've lost some content due to formatting/

Comment: I have update dear mates please help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have this output `* ** ***`, you're may be looking for [str_repeat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php)

```
<?php
$a="*";
for($b=1;$b<=3;$b++)
{
    echo str_repeat($a, $b)."<br/>";
}

echo "<br/>";
```

And the solution without any builtin function would be the following:

```
<?php
$a="*";
for($b=1;$b<=3;$b++)
{
    echo $a."<br/>";
    $a .='*';
}

echo "<br/>";
```

Comment: Can we did this without using any inbuilt functions?

Comment: @KamalHasija you should specify this into your post, please update it

Comment: Thanks very much Sir @smarber

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) inside your loop like this

```
$a="*";
for($b=1;$b<=3;$b++)
{
    echo str_repeat($a,$b).'<br>';
}
```

Result

```
*
**
***
```